# Can Oracle Database run on Microsoft Nano Server?

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g-r2, windows, windows-server

Microsoft Nano Server is attractive alternative to a heavier installation of Microsoft Windows Server 2016. Can Oracle Database be prepared to run this way?